# How to run all cucumber functional automated test cases in single browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I am new to cucumber testing as well as selenium testing.Please help me to run all cucumber test cases in single browser.As for now i am creating new WebDriver object in each cucumber step_def for feature file.

Comment: Provide some code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is, Using / passing the same Web Driver object across your step_def. From your Question i assume, you have multiple Step Def files, If the stories are small and related put all of them in a single step_def file and have a single Web driver object. If it is not the case, invoke every step_def with a predefined Driver object that is globally declared in the configuration loader.

Comment: Thank you for help but could you elaborate more as i have defined one helper class where i have method to evoke browser and in all step_def i am calling that method to evoke browser.So where to define that browser so that i could gate that browser in all step_def.And i could not put all step_def in one.

Comment: Then its much simpler, have a initialize method(or a constructor) in your helper class to instantiate your driver object. Then have a getter for the same. Now you can call the getter wherever you want. Only thing is, Have your Helper class common to all your step_def. If you still need some help, better show your classes, so that we can suggest where you need to modify.

Answer (score 1):

For using one browser to run all test cases use singleton design pattern i.e make class with private constructor  and define class instance variable with a private access specifier.Create a method in that class and check that class is null or not and if it is null than create a new   instance of class and return that instance to calling method.for example i am posting my code.

```
class OpenBrowserHelp {
private WebDriver driver;
private static OpenBrowserHelp browserHelp;

private OpenBrowserHelp() {
    this.driver = new FirefoxDriver()
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

public static OpenBrowserHelp getOpenBrowserHelp() {
    if (null == browserHelp) {
        browserHelp = new OpenBrowserHelp();
    }
    return browserHelp;
}

WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver
}

void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver
}

public void printSingleton() {
    System.out.println("Inside print Singleton");
}
```

Now, where ever you need to create browser instance than use

```
 WebDriver driver = OpenBrowserHelp.getOpenBrowserHelp().getDriver();
```